# Trick PHP running behind mod_php and change host and protocol

Tags: php, apache2

I'm migrating legacy apps to docker and I need to "trick" php into thinking that it runs on the exact same environment as it used before.

Basically, the app used to run on an apache2 with mod_php and the PHP code does something somewhere that says "If you've been called with HTTP, set the link for the images to http."

My docker image is now accessible locally with http only. But I would like to still fake PHP into thinking that it has been accessed with HTTPS.

I suppose that Apache should rewrite the `$_SERVER['HTTPS']` variable but I can't find in the documentation how I could do that.

Here is my current configuration for my app:

```
<VirtualHost *:8080>
     DocumentRoot "/var/www/app"

     <Directory /var/www/app>
         Require all granted
         Order allow,deny
         Allow from all
         Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
         AllowOverride All
     </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: If your images are set via relative links, its the browers concern to determine if https is used or not (will use same as main page). Have a look at the raw html output. If the links are relavite you have to rewrite them to absolute links to accomplish this.

Comment: No, the images are set with absolute links in the application based on server variables values, that's the issue for me :(

Comment: Ok i see, so you are sure you have to set `$_SERVER['HTTPS']` so the links will get `https`?

Comment: _Small Point_ `Require all granted` Good, Apache 2.4 command. `Order allow,deny Allow from all` Bad, Apache 2.2 command. Apache can get a bit confused if you use both together

Comment: Yes exactly, when I manually set $_SERVER['HTTPS'] = 'on' in the code, it works fine. I just would like this to be handled by apache instead of php code

Comment: Then use `mod_env` and use `SetEnv HTTPS 1` (or on, afaik it has to be not empty) in your config.

Comment: SetEnv was close but didn't allow to overwrite values set by Apache like HTTP_HOST. I ended up adding a line to the hosts in the container, and adding an other virtual host as a reverse proxy to hit the mod_php virtual host with the correct host and protocol. Anyways, thank you for your help, I went faster!